# CURL script causes apache to hang for 1 subdomain to hang (Even with different sessions)

Tags: php, apache, curl

I have a php curl script below that emulates a browser to login to a site an execute a script on REMOTE server and output the result.

The script on REMOTE server it is calling uses `passthru(mysqldump ....);`

If I stop the curl script part way though by hitting control + p and do not allow curl_close on script then it just hangs forever when trying to access the application via that url (client.domain.com) even for new sessions with different cookie than curl script.

All the other clients are unaffected and database access is still possible. Is there an apache setting to change? Restarting apache fixes the issue.

All clients have their own database and OWN subdomain:

client.domain.com --> own db
client2.domain.com --> own db
client3.domain.com --> own db

I am using cent os 6 and Apache/2.2.15

Here is the script I am calling to emulate browser.

```
<?php
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
$store_url = 'http://subdomain.domain.com';
$username = 'username';
$password = 'password';
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $store_url.'/index.php/login');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POST, 2);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "username=$username&password=$password");

$data = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

preg_match_all('|Set-Cookie: (.*);|U', $data, $matches);   
$cookies = implode('; ', $matches[1]);

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $store_url.'/index.php/config/do_mysqldump_backup');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);  
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookies);
curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

Comment: It sounds like the remote script is locking the database (or something else) until the connection is closed.

Comment: I can access database fine while this is happening. I also use innodb so I don't think it will lock using mysqldump

Comment: Yeah, it seems like it's happening at the server level, since it's specific to just that script, and there's nothing in the script that does any locking.